# Access all User Session in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am building a struts 2 application with JPA. A user can login into the application multiple times. I want

1. user to be able to view all his session in a grid and probably highlight the current session and optionally the user can select a session and terminate it.
2. An administrator should also be able to see all the logged in users and can also view all the sessions of each logged in user and also can optionally terminate any of the sessions.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `HttpSessionBindingListener` is what are you looking for.
I won't write down the complete code, just suggest you a way you can do it:

You can add a static field (Map) to your `User class (DTO)` where you will store all active `sessions of users`. :

e.g `private static Map<User, HttpSession> usersSessions= new HashMap<User, HttpSession>();`

Then make `User class` implemets `HttpSessionBindingListener`. This way you can specify `valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event)` method in which you can grab actually created `session` and put it into your `usersSessions` like this :

`usersSessions.put(this, event.getSession());`

In `valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event)` method then :

`usersSessions.remove(this);` to remove `users session` after `logout`.

This way you have `Map` of all of your `active sessions` also with information to which user it belongs to. IMO you can figure out your other problems easily with this.

Comment: Does it make any sense to use a ThreadLocal object or pattern to monitor user sessions. Anyway thanks for your answer. Let me try it out.

Comment: I don't think so. You have to store sessions in static field visible to all users, because you want to have possibility to invalidate session from admins account. This won't be possible without this static field, because you can't get access from one session to another - so you can't invalidate it either. But this way you can get actual users sessions from that static field and invalidate the desired one easily.