# logging out old session and and continuing in new session with same user ID and Password in Java Web Apps

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, web-applications

Suppose a person is logged in with user id and password in an app. Now with same user id and password he is trying to log without logging out from first session. I want to make it that it willlog out from and first session and continue with new one automatically.

Struts2, JSP , Java are technologies , i m using for my apps.

Problems facing

1. IE 8 giving same session id in same machine if we open in new tab or window. Not able to differentiate between different login from same machine. 
   How to set own session id?
2. Banking application like SBI sites and all works like that only , how does it work real time?
3. I want to replicate same thing like SBI bank sites work on online transaction. Send message session out in first window if you open again in new window

Please let me know how does this logging part in details.
Thanks.

This is my filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("FirstFilter : In filter doFilter before doFilter...");
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request ;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response ;

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    String userId=req.getParameter("username");
    String password=req.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println(" : : " + req.getParameter("username")) ;
    System.out.println(" : " + req.getServletPath());


    LoggedInUserVO userProfVOSession = null ;
    if(session != null) {
    String  sessionId=session.getId();
        userProfVOSession = (LoggedInUserVO)session.getAttribute("LoggedInUser") ;
        //check for login id password and session for single user sign in
        if(null!=userProfVOSession){
        if(userProfVOSession.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userId) && userProfVOSession.getUserPassword().equals(password) && userProfVOSession.getSessionId().equals(sessionId)){
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("in duplicate");
        }
        }
    }       

    if(userProfVOSession == null) {
        if("/populatelogin.action".equals(req.getServletPath()) || "/login.action".equals(req.getServletPath())||"/images/Twalk-Logo-4-green.png".equals (req.getServletPath())||"css/twalk.css".equals( req.getServletPath() )) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res) ;
        } else {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("Entryindex.jsp").forward(req, res) ;
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res) ;
    }
```

Comment: just go through this might be this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128587/access-all-user-session-in-struts-2

Comment: your link just says that we can store all the session in Map...my problem is how will you catch new session from different tab or new window from same machine...As IE 8 using same session id..How you are going to differentiate.

Comment: i do not know much about this aspect but Session is not being created by IE or any browser but the session being created and maintained by container.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your requirement leads to web security vulnerability.If a person is already logged in, then his session must be active.Now the scenario is like this:

If you tries to login again with the same credentials,  he wll be automatically logged in.
If you want to kill the old session for every login, then what you need to do is , you need to get a new session every time when you login, so your old session will be expired.You can achieve this by just writing a filter.In this filter check whether the user is already associated with a session or not, if yes, then invalidate his current session and start new one.This will solve the issue of multiple login attempts.

Remember that when a session is initiated, then the server is sending a cookie back to the user.Henceforth for every subsequent request made, this cookie will be transmitted to the server. Even if that if you open multiple tabs in browsers, this same cookie only is sent back to the server.

Hope I understood this.

Comment: i have added my filter in description ...you can see that , all request is going through that filter, how can i check that the request is coming from new window or tab as tabs or new window is sending same session id of same machine...Imporatnt question is how can you filter down a request from new window or tab or different machine..

Comment: In fact , you may not be able to identify that the request is coming from different browser.But all that you can do is that if the request is coming from a different system, then it the filter you can get that users IP address by using request.getRemoteAddr().Howeever, in Firefox you can do this way that <a href="some url" target="_newtab">new tab</a> and in javascript , window.open('page.html','_newtab');So In this case, you need to trap event and send some identification to server and on server side based on this value you can do it.But,I have not tried this way.

Comment: how can i redirect message that old session is expired or logged out from that new session.Please give some code snippet

Comment: There are session listeners for this job using that you can check whether the session is expired or not.

Comment: ok..if in destory method , how should i forward a jsp containing the message to that particular machine or tab....though we are in new session ...