# How to manually kill a specific HttpSession by ID

Tags: java, session, jsf, sessionid

We need a functionality of killing a specific session (by session ID) from some kind of an admin panel.

I attempted using the following approach:

```
public static void killSession(String sid) {

    HttpSessionContext sc = FacesUtil.getSession().getSessionContext();
    HttpSession session=sc.getSession(sid);        

    session.invalidate();
}
```

However

1. HttpSessionContext, and getSessionContext() and
   getSession(sessionId) methods of a session are all deprecated (for seemingly paranoid security reasons)
2. The above code also gets a null session when invoked in an ApplicationScoped JSF managed bean

I'm seeking an alternative way of achieving the functionality.

Comment: How about sending additional GET/POST request with set `JSESSIONID` cookie of needed value to an HttpServlet that invalidates its current session?

Comment: @Dmytro, thanks for the suggestion. I already thought of that as a last resort. As a best practice, I sought a way to accomplish this from within JSF. As a last resort, I will try that, but it looks like as of Java EE 5, the methods of invalidating a session from another session seems to be deprecated and can turn out to be impossible to accomplish.

Comment: when doPost/doGet methods of invalidating servlet invoked, the current session id in their contex will be of value that you'd specified in the `JSESSIONID` cookie before. So your servlet invalidated needed specified session. :)

Comment: @Dmytro can you provide a sample code fragment demonstrating your suggestion? If you post it as an answer and it works, I'll surely accept the answer and vote at least +1

Comment: If you track logged-in users in the DB as well, it's better to set a boolean there in the DB which is then checked on every request. This way it will also work without much pain on distributes systems and won't result in surprises (exceptions) when the session get invalidated in midst of a request.

Comment: @BalusC I have no problem tracking the connected users, thanks to your answers to my previous two questions, I already accomplished that. The only remaining functional business requirement is killing a session of a user from an admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't invalidate `session` from another `session` due to security reasons. What you can do is to manually store all `sessions` in some `static attribute` available to admin. So user logs in, you add him and his `session` to this attribute (usually a `Map/HashMap` with user as a `key` and `session` as `value`).

Look at my older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129360/1317692) and you will get an idea.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm already storing some info for each connected user with their session ID in an Application-scoped managed bean - this already serves for getting a read-only view of all active sessions with connected users.